# How to use the file path API from Swift to get documents directory and create filenames

Tags: path, avfoundation, swift, xcode6, nsdocumentdirectory

I have this code to record video with AVFoundation but I don't know how convert to Swift

```
- (void)startRecording 
{    
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss"];
    NSString* dateTimePrefix = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    int fileNamePostfix = 0;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = nil;
    do
        filePath =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/%@-%i.mp4", documentsDirectory, dateTimePrefix, fileNamePostfix++];
    while ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]);

    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"file://" stringByAppendingString:filePath]];
    [self.fileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:fileURL recordingDelegate:self];
}
```

I don't know how work with  this paths in Swift..

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

Here's how you get the document directory

```
// NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
//   NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
      .DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)

// NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
let documentsDirectory = paths[0] as String
```

Here's how you do the filename picking with the postfix

```
var filePath:String? = nil
var fileNamePostfix = 0
do {
    // filePath =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/%@-%i.mp4", 
    //   documentsDirectory, dateTimePrefix, fileNamePostfix++];
    filePath = 
       "\(documentsDirectory)/\(dateTimePrefix)-\(fileNamePostfix++).mp4"
} while (NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(filePath))
```

This code is just a straight port of your code, except that I removed the `/` before `documentsDirectory` because it is already an absolute path.

Comment: yes, but ho obtain pàth file://...                                    do
        filePath =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/%@-%i.mp4", documentsDirectory, dateTimePrefix, fileNamePostfix++];
    while ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]);
    
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"file://" stringByAppendingString:filePath]];
    [self.fileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:fileURL recordingDelegate:self];

Comment: How convert this line, to save in the path ?   [self.fileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:fileURL recordingDelegate:self];   I can't call delegate

Comment: Does your class implement the protocol?  It would be a lot better to make another question with the specific line, what you tried, and the exact error message you are getting.